# Error in numpy nanmean

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, nan

I have an array with floats and NaNs yet when I call `numpy.nanmean()` on the array I get `NaN`as result. How is this possible?

This is a sample of the array `ages`

```
[22.0 38.0 26.0 35.0 35.0 nan 54.0 2.0 27.0 14.0 4.0 58.0 20.0 39.0 14.0
 55.0 2.0 nan 31.0 nan 35.0 34.0 15.0 28.0 8.0 38.0 nan 19.0 nan nan 40.0
 nan nan 66.0 28.0 42.0 nan 21.0 18.0 14.0 40.0 27.0 nan 3.0 19.0 nan nan
 nan nan 18.0 7.0 21.0 49.0 29.0 65.0 nan 21.0 28.5 5.0 11.0 22.0 38.0 45.0
...
```

the shape

```
(891,)
```

and `np.nanmean(ages)` returns `nan`

Comment: Because all are `NaNs`?

Comment: nope, that's the point

Comment: Are you calling `numpy.nanmean()` along an axis or across all elements?

Comment: the dimension is `(891,)` I tried both with `axis=0` and without specifying it but I get the same result

Comment: Hmm, that's weird.

Comment: I added more details, I hope that helps

Comment: What version of numpy and what is the exact dtype of your array?

Comment: I'm using `1.11.0` and `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: even `np.nanmean(ages[0:6])` returns `nan`

Comment: I think this has to do with how your data was generated.  It's very strange that your array's dtype is `ndarray` when it doesn't look like you have any objects in your array.  Try `np.nanmean(ages.astype('float64'))`

Comment: That worked!! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As we figured out in the comments above, having a dtype of `numpy.ndarray` in a one dimensional list is strange when it appears you only have floats and `NaN`s in there.  This makes me think that you are generating your data in a flawed manner, something like manually creating an array from a file's contents without removing empty lines, etc.

To solve this, convert (or view) your array to a different dtype.  Try

```
np.nanmean(ages.astype('float64'))
```

If that works, you should permanently change its dtype

```
ages = ages.astype('float64')
```

and revisit your array generation as I'm 99% sure something is off there.

Comment: How could the data be generated in a flawed manner? I have this issue and the `astype` trick isn't working...

Comment: How are you loading your data into the numpy array?  If it is in some way tabular, you may try loading it with `pandas` (e.g. `x= pd.read_table(...)`), inspecting the resultant series or dataframe, then converting to an numpy array with `x.values` as `pandas` has more robust file loading for many more formats than `numpy`.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same error. In my case, I had some `inf` and `-inf` values inside the array, which are valid float numbers, but would cause any `mean()` function to break, evidently.

Filtering out the infinite values solved for me.